# Does JavaFX FilteredList keep the same order as its source (an ObservableList)?

Tags: java, list, javafx

I looked through the document on Oracle's web and didn't find anything about the ordering of FilteredList.  If FilteredList doesn't maintain the relative ordering of the original list, is there an easy way to swap two elements in a FilteredList?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that it maintains the order, even though it's not documented. Anything else would be highly counter-intuitive. "Wraps an ObservableList and filters its content" implies that the filtered list is the "same as" the source list except that it omits filtered items, and since lists are inherently ordered I think this implies the ordering is maintained.

Comment: I guess you're right.  Thanks.